# Question on Legendre equation

Tags: special-functions

I have a doubt. If Legendre equation has a polynomial solution, is the constant $l$ in $l(l+1)$ necessarily a integer number? Asked in another way, is possible $l(l+1)$ be a integer if $l$ is not an integer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (although this is not really relevant for the Legendre polynomials):
$$l = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$$
$$l(l+1) = 1$$

Comment: I think it is relevant because you can have physical relevant solutions in the polar angle when $l$ is not integer. I was reading a book saying that l must be integer to have physical meaning. What do you think?

Comment: It is not relevant for physics. Not considering half-integer intrinsic angular momentum (spin), the (orbital) angular momentum quantum number is always an integer. The reason that your text book says that non-integer $l$ is not relevant, is that in that case the resulting solution of the Schrodinger equation is not square-integrable - and hence the solution does not fulfill the probability postulate of quantum mechanics.